# custom image on jquery ui dialog

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am using Jquery UI Dialog on my asp.net view like this:

```
$("#dialog-dial-prefix").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 470,
        resizeable: true,
        buttons: {
            "OK": function () {
 $(this).dialog("close");

                                }


                      ,
                       "Cancel": function () {
                           $(this).dialog("close");
                            var selectedDialPrefix = $("#SelecteddialprefixId").val();
                            $("#" + selectedDialPrefix).focus();
                        }
        }
    });
```

This Dialog has two buttons Ok and Cancel. I want to apply custom images ( which I have as png images) to these buttons. How can I add buttons and remove the text which is appearing as Ok and cancel on Jquery ui dialog buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve this by overwriting the default css of the buttons

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane button { 
    text-indent: -9999em; /* hides the text */
    color: transparent; /* also hides text */
    background-image: url(/path/to/image.png); /*replaces default image */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

add the dialog's id if you want to target a specific dialog box

Comment: @Dooku where to add dialog id ?

Comment: `#dialog-id.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane button {... }`

Comment: add `background-repeat:no-repeat;`

Comment: It worked without id but not with id like this: #dialog-dial-prefix.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane button { 
    text-indent: -9999em; /* hides the text */
    color: transparent; /* also hides text */
    background-image: url(images/login-icon.png); /*replaces default image */
}

Comment: well i was just assuming that the .ui-dialog will be placed on the original div. I guess I was wrong. I need to see the html to be more specific